# how to make a button inactive in pyqt?

Tags: python, pyqt6

The QMainWindow window contains the QTableView and QPushButton. Necessary :1 when the cell is highlighted, the button will be active setEnabled(True) I did this when connecting the signal . 2 how to do so that if you remove the cell selection, for example, to an empty place in the table, the button changes the mode to setEnabled(False)

```
import sys

from PyQt6.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QTableView, QVBoxLayout, QWidget


class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.buttonEdit = QPushButton('Edit')
        self.qtable = QTableView()
        self.buttonEdit.setEnabled(False)

        data = [['1', '2', '3'],
                ['4', '5', '6'],
                ['7', '8', '9']]

        self.model = QStandardItemModel()

        for row in range(len(data)):
            for column in range(len(data[row])):
                item = QStandardItem(data[row][column])
                self.model.setItem(row, column, item)

        self.qtable.setModel(self.model)

        self.qtable.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self.on_click)

        self.box = QVBoxLayout()
        self.box.addWidget(self.qtable)
        self.box.addWidget(self.buttonEdit)

        self.setLayout(self.box)

    def on_click(self):
        if self.qtable.selectionModel():
            self.buttonEdit.setEnabled(True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    main_window = MyWindow()
    main_window.resize(600, 800)

    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def on_click:
    self.buttonEdit.setEnabled(self.qtable.selectionModel().hasSelection())
```

You should not need to check, if the selectionModel exists.
When the selectionModel has a selection, then the buttinEdit is enabled otherwise disabled.

Comment: Even simpler: `self.buttonEdit.setEnabled(bool(self.qtable.selectedIndexes()))`

Comment: self.buttonEdit.setEnabled(bool(self.qtable.selectedIndexes())) this solved my problem thank you